# How to displays results for contacts which have ACR in the search

Tags: search, global-search, accountcontactrelation

We have enabled ACR (accountcontactrelation) in our Salesforce Org to stop duplication of contacts.

When a user types in the contact details (name , email) in the search bar there is ability to hover over and see all the indirect relationships that contact has.

However if you don’t use this technique and press enter in the global search it always shows the primary (direct ) relationship of the contact account and not the indirect relationships .

The question I have is there anyway I can get the indirect relationships to show in the global search result either natively or custom component , and any screenshots / pocs to shar eve much appreciated

Regards
Masond3

Comment: I think yo should customize the Contact record page layout to include related lists or report charts that highlight indirect relationships. While this doesn't change the global search functionality, it makes indirect relationships more visible when viewing a contact record.

Comment: Yeah we have it as a related list on the contact.  But from a user experience it would mean that a user would need to click on the contact to find the corresponding associations. So was hoping to do something within the  search display

Comment: I don't think this requirement is doable with the current level of customization of the platform...

Comment: Hmm. There must be something, seems crazy that a feature been enabled  but an unable to search on it. I wonder if I created another look upfield on the acr object to the account and populate that would that show search results

Comment: The global search results for contacts only show the direct account relationship, not the indirect ones. However, you can use the Account Contact Relationship object to create a [custom report](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.shared_contacts_custom_report_types.htm&type=5) that shows the indirect relationships for contacts.